# How to delete a list in Spring data Mongo DB Mongo repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongorepository

I have one Offering and this offering have multiple countries.So I want to delete the respective country in mongo repository.so how can I delete from spring data mongodb repository.
Please find my JSON below.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e0e1758da2b685eef727f"),
  "offeringId" : "PMRS674913",
  "offeringType" : "FEATURE",
  "service" : "HBOGO",
  "countries" : [
     {
       "country" : "OTT",
       "isoCode" : "124",
       "startDate" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00",
       "endDate" : "2015-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00"
     },
     {
       "country" : "United States",
       "isoCode" : " 456",
       "startDate" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00",
       "endDate" : "2015-01-31T0000:00.000-05:00"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query to do so:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "countries" : { $elemMatch : { "country" : "OTT" } } } ,
    { $pull : { "countries" : { "country" : "OTT" } } },
    { multi : true }
)
```

In `Spring` you have to use following syntax :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("countries")
        .elemMatch(Criteria.where("country").is("United States")));

Update update = new Update();
update.pull("countries", new BasicDBObject("country", "United States"));

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, collection);
```

Comment: use `{ multi : true }` if you have same country multiple time in list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harsh Patel.But I want to delete the entire country object from Countries based on country name

Comment: Did you mean entire `countries` key?
can you provide me final output you want after update?

Comment: Hi Harsh,Below is the my actual json.{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e0e1758da2b685eef727f"),
  "offeringId" : "PMRS674913",
  "offeringType" : "FEATURE",
  "service" : "HBOGO",
  "countries" : [
     {
       "country" : "OTT",
       "isoCode" : "124",
       "startDate" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00",
       "endDate" : "2015-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00"
     },
     {
       "country" : "United States",
       "isoCode" : " 456",
       "startDate" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00",
       "endDate" : "2015-01-31T0000:00.000-05:00"
     }
   ]
}

Comment: After deleting the country OTT final output will be { "_id" : ObjectId("565e0e1758da2b685eef727f"),
  "offeringId" : "PMRS674913",
  "offeringType" : "FEATURE",
  "service" : "HBOGO",
  "countries" : [
      {
       "country" : "United States",
       "isoCode" : " 456",
       "startDate" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00",
       "endDate" : "2015-01-31T0000:00.000-05:00"
     }
   ]
}

Comment: and after deleting the country and  my expected out put will be                         { "_id" : ObjectId("565e0e1758da2b685eef727f"),
  "offeringId" : "PMRS674913",
  "offeringType" : "FEATURE",
  "service" : "HBOGO",
 }